# Call function only once if bool value changed in update() method

Tags: c++, events, triggers, boolean

I need help. I have an update() method which called every tick. This method has a lot of functions, just like this one:

```
if (myBoolValue)
    some stuff
else
    another stuff
```

But how to call this "some stuff" and "another stuff" only once if myBoolValue will be changed without calling it on every tick?

Comment: Add `bool oldValue` and compare it to `myBoolValue`. Run `your stuff` only when `oldValue != myBoolValue`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've thinking about it but in this case the number of my variables will be doubled (i already had something about 300+ booleans). Maybe there is any method to create "universal" comparing value?

Comment: Or register a callback that the site of changing the bool calls the callback instead

Comment: @PasserBy Can you write some example?

Comment: You tagged events yourself, that is literally what events do.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call both why not do this?

```
If(myboolvalue)
    Somestuff;
If(anotherboolvalue)
    Someotherstuff
```

Comment: I can call both of them. But i need to call them only once (they are in update() method and must be there).

Comment: Okie I assume it's something like an arduino. You can set a static flag then